# Does particle も eat particle の?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, particle-も

Reading [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/80862/7944) I noticed an embarrassing hole in my basic knowledge. From the answer:

> 今日は私も誕生日です。
> Today is (your birthday, and) also my birthday.

Without the 'also' part we would have

> 今日は私**の**誕生日です。

But I think the original sentence (with も) is a different structure. Rather than replacing の with も I think that 私 has been promoted to a topic and も is actually replacing は in this case. Is this correct?

If I'm right about the above then how would you add も whilst still preserving the possessive structure? I feel that 私**のも**誕生日です and 私**もの**誕生日です would both be ungrammatical. That would leave me with 私**の**誕生日**も**です. But that also looks weird. Finally, employing も's tendency to move to the right in sentences, I would fix this by writing 私**の**誕生日で**も**あります. But, if I'm not mistaken, that's a rather stiff and formal sentence.

Are the things I've said above correct? What is the most natural, informal way to express this simple statement? Is it possible to preserve the possessive structure, or must we promote 私 to a topic as in the original sentence?

Comment: でもある and ではある are nowhere near as stiff as である itself, I'm pretty sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as 私も今日は誕生日です: Me too, today is (one's) birthday. → Today is my birthday too.

"(One's) birthday" is interpreted as "my birthday" because of the effect of the parallel topic 私も.